# SQL Query error ' multi-part identifier vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources.MachineID could not be bound'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create a custom report in System Center Configuration Manager using SQL Server Report Builder.

I have already selected the dataset and the connection to the SQL database is successfully established. I have to write a Query in SQL to fetch the data from the views. This is the SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
(
    vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources.MachineID,
    vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources.Name,
    vSMS_CombinedDeviceResource.CurrentLogonUser 
    FROM vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources 
    INNER JOIN vSMS_Update_ComplianceStatus 
    ON vSMS_CombinedDeviceResource.MachineID = vSMS_Update_ComplianceStatus.MachineID 
    INNER JOIN v_UpdateDeploymentSummary 
    ON v_UpdateDeploymentSummary.CI_ID = vSMS_Update_ComplianceStatus.CI_ID 
    WHERE v_UpdateDeploymentSummary.CollectionName=@CollectionName 
        AND vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources.ClientState!=0
)
```

But I am getting an error as

> The multi-part identifier vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources.MachineID
>   could not be bound

Could anyone please specify the error that I have made in the SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a wrong ( ) after the select word and around the rest of query

```
  SELECT vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources.MachineID
          ,vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources.Name
          ,vSMS_CombinedDeviceResource.CurrentLogonUser 
  FROM vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources 
  INNER JOIN vSMS_Update_ComplianceStatus ON vSMS_CombinedDeviceResource.MachineID = vSMS_Update_ComplianceStatus.MachineID 
  INNER JOIN v_UpdateDeploymentSummary ON v_UpdateDeploymentSummary.CI_ID = vSMS_Update_ComplianceStatus.CI_ID 
  WHERE v_UpdateDeploymentSummary.CollectionName=@CollectionName 
  AND vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources.ClientState!=0
```